# Sorting tableview cells from lowest to highest

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, sorting

I have a tableview with these fields filling the table. locTextArray contains a distance in feet.

How would I sort the cells from the least amount in feet to the most?

I figured I could sort the array, but that would mismatch all the other arrays.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell : MainViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainCell") as! MainViewCell

        cell.cellTitle.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]  //title
        cell.cellText.text = textArray[indexPath.row]   // text

        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
        cell.userCount.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(Double(priceArray [indexPath.row])!)  //price

        cell.cellDate.text = timeArray[indexPath.row] //time
        cell.cellAddress.text = locTextArray [indexPath.row] //distance in feet

             return cell as MainViewCell
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have so many arrays? You should have 1 array with a model object in it...

Answer (score 1):

It would all be easier if you used objects.  Create a custom object with properties (name, text, price, time, locText).  Use one array of those to control your table data and sort it by whichever property makes sense.

Then your code would become something like:

```
let obj = objArray[indexPath.row]
cell.cellTitle.text = obj.name
cell.cellText.text = obj.text
// ...
```